# WinRT Sharing Source Contract both HTML and Files

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

It doesn't appear that I can provide both HTML content and file content in the DataRequestedEvent handler.

If I provide HTML content (via args.Request.Data.SetHtmlFormat(xxx)) and file (via args.Request.Data.SetStorageItems(xxx)) the Share charm says "There's nothing to share".

Anyone got any ideas or is this by design?

Answer (score 3):

```
var htmlExample = "<p>Here is our store logo: <img src='images/logo.png'>.</p>";
var htmlFormat = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.HtmlFormatHelper.createHtmlFormat(htmlExample);
request.data.setHtmlFormat(htmlFormat);
```

full exemple here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackage.sethtmlformat

Comment: That, unfortunately, doesn't do it.  As far as I can tell, the real issue is in the Mail app preview.  Yes, you can share out multiple data formats but if there's a StorageItem attachment(s), Mail ignores the title and message.

Answer (score 0):

If time for generating the content is more that 200ms share charm says "There's nothing to share".
You can avoid this problem with DataProvider.

```
       args.Request.Data.SetDataProvider(StandardDataFormats.Html,
                    new DataProviderHandler(this.OnDeferredHTMLRequestedHandler)); 

       args.request.Data.SetDataProvider(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems,
                    new DataProviderHandler(this.OnDeferredStorageItemsRequestedHandler));
```

You can find more information here:

[How to support pull operations (XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871375.aspx)